# JSP does not create class of servlet on linux

Tags: java, linux, jsp, tomcat, servlets

This is my JSP code which is called from html file...

```
<%
System.out.println("DEBUG1");
int id = (request.getRequestedSessionId()+request.getRemoteAddr()).hashCode();
System.out.println("DEBUG2");
SERVLETCLASS d = new SERVLETCLASS(id); // Stuck here
System.out.println("DEBUG3");
String sen = request.getParameter("data");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
System.out.println("SEN: "+sen);
String rtn = d.runJob(name, sen);
System.out.println("RTN: "+rtn);
%>
```

I developed a project on Windows with Eclipse and tried WAR deployment test on Windows. It worked very well as I wanted.

But when I copy WAR file to Linux and tried to deploy on it, **new SERVLETCLASS(id)** is not working. So terminal shows only DEBUG1 and DEBUG2.

Of course, I changed server.xml in Linux

Is there difference between Windows and Linux? Especially on CentOS 7.

p.s. I used Apache Tomcat 8.0.24

**EDIT**

I'm sorry but I can't upload class code because of this is part of work from my company. It just invokes several methods as in JavaSE. I ported JavaSE project to JavaEE.

But thanks to you RC., I think that I found why it happened as log shows

**LOGS** (from catalina.-today-.log) / click to see large image

[image]

I manually installed apr, apr-util, pcre and tomcat. But why this happens?

And one more error not existed in Windows,

```
03-Aug-2015 15:20:15.546 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ChatBot' did not find a matching property.
```

Well, I think this is not the problem, but I installed eclipse in Linux too.

Comment: "new SERVLETCLASS(id) is not working. So terminal shows only DEBUG1 and DEBUG2." - and anything/exception afterwards?

Comment: Case sensitive file system under linux (maybe)

Comment: @Smutje Nothing... I used __tail -f /[TOMCAT INSTALL FOLDER]/logs/catalina.out__ to show logs from Tomcat

Comment: @RC. I checked it already.

Comment: Hum, in a temp dir in your home directory under linux: 1/ wget http://apache.crihan.fr/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.24/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.24.tar.gz 2/ tar xvzf apache-tomcat-8.0.24.tar.gz 3/ chmod +x apache-tomcat-8.0.24/bin/catalina.sh 4/ apache-tomcat-8.0.24/bin/catalina.start 5/ browse localhost:8080 and make sure tomcat is running 6/ copy your war into apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps 7/ check you JSP 8/ zip apache-tomcat-8.0.24/logs and share the zip with us if not working

Comment: (be sure to stop any tomcat instance before anything). Also edit you question and add code for `SERVLETCLASS` and `web.xml`

Comment: Case-insensitive Windows file system springs to mind (as a war is unpacked). Also check the path: `<%@ page import="PACKAGE.PATH" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this problem by manually re-installing all tomcat/httpd related components...

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

The code looks strange - seems heavily abbreviated? There are two options - either your `SERVLETCLASS` (is this really the name of your class?) contains an endless loop (and the request is never ending) or it throws an Exception or Error that gets swallowed somewhere else.

You can try debugging this by wrapping the call in a `try/catch` clause:

```
System.out.println("DEBUG2");
try {
    SERVLETCLASS d = new SERVLETCLASS(id);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("DEBUG3");
```

This way you'll see if there's an exception or error that's swallowed. If you find something, continue from there.

Also, I hope that your SERVLETCLASS is not actually a servlet, as you typically don't create servlets yourself but leave this task to the application server. Do future maintainers a favour and have your logic in a non-servlet class if you instantiate it the way you're doing here.